# django built in authenticator does not work

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using the built in authenticater by django and have encountered 2 issues:

Despite placing login decorators as such :

```
class sales_home(View):
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'sales/home.html')
```

I am still able to access the home view by typing it into the URL. The login decorator only works when I clear my browser caches, which is not a solution in production.

The second issue with the built-in authenticator is that the request.user.id returns None.

I am currently trying to display data based on the user's own inputs. 
Here is my API call :

```
class ChartData(APIView):
authentication_classes = []
permission_classes = []
def get(self, request, format=None):
    current_user = request.user
    sales_rev_data = Sales_project.objects.values_list('sales_project_est_rev', flat=True).filter(sales_project_status = 'p4').filter(sales_extras = current_user.id)
    labels = Sales_project.objects.values_list('sales_project_closing_date', flat=True).filter(sales_project_status = 'p4')

    data = {
        "labels1": labels,
        "default1": sales_rev_data,
        "labels2": labels,
        "default2": sales_rev_data,
    }   

    return Response(data)
```

because `current_user.id` returns None, I am unable to access the data that corresponds to the user.

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: add your rest framework settings. also try to change your `authentication_classes` and `permission_classes` with these: `authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]` and `permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]`

Comment: Thank you brother! it works , you saved my life!

Comment: Although this manage to solve the displaying of data, im still able to access the home page without logging in , it would be great if someone has an explanation!

Comment: add permission class and authentication class to your home view as well, it should resolve the issue

Comment: i've tried that , it seems like the cache problem still exists , i will try to find some solutions for it and update this post if i found any , in the meantime if someone knows why please tell me! thank you!